# How to use a string in a function name

Tags: ios, swift, function, uibutton

I have these functions:

```
private func chooseOfferButton1Tapped() {
        let vc = ChooseRdvVC()
        vc.offerCatched = arrayCatched![0]
        HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    private func chooseOfferButton2Tapped() {
        let vc = ChooseRdvVC()
        vc.offerCatched = arrayCatched![1]
        HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
                   ...
```

up to:

```
                   ...

private func chooseOfferButton50Tapped() {
        let vc = ChooseRdvVC()
        vc.offerCatched = arrayCatched![49]
        HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Here's how I call the functions:

```
let index = "chooseOfferButton\(oneViewSize)Tapped"
chooseOfferButton.addTarget(self,
                            action: Selector(index),
                            for: .touchUpInside)
```

where `oneViewSize` is the number that changes

I'm looking for a way to avoid writing this same function over and over only with 2 numbers changing. How can I use a string in a function name? Or a for loop? Or is there another way? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others there's only one action needed. The index is passed through the `tag` property of the button.

---

Instead of putting the index into the selector assign the index (aka `oneViewSize`) to the `tag`

```
chooseOfferButton.addTarget(self,
                            action: #selector(chooseOfferButtonTapped),
                            for: .touchUpInside)
chooseOfferButton.tag = oneViewSize
```

On the callee side get the index from the button (the `sender`)

```
@objc private func chooseOfferButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = ChooseRdvVC()
    let index = sender.tag
    vc.offerCatched = arrayCatched[index]
    HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Ans please declare `arrayCatched` non-optional as you force unwrap it anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using table view then you need to use the `tag` property of `UIButton` in your `cellForRowAt indexPath` method

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(chooseOfferButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

```
@objc func chooseOfferButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    let vc = ChooseRdvVC()
    vc.offerCatched = arrayCatched[sender.tag]
    HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Or if you are using `@IBOutletCollection` then you need to set the tag for each button and set same button click action for each button

```
 @IBOutlet var btnChooseOffer: [UIButton]!

 @IBAction func chooseOfferButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let vc = ChooseRdvVC()
    vc.offerCatched = arrayCatched[sender.tag]
    HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: I'm not using a table view nor a storyboard, just regular buttons with targets

Comment: please refer this link - https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/what-is-an-iboutletcollection-in-ios-78cfbc4080a1

Comment: for how you can refactor your button code